# Cross-Threading issue when trying to access a static method

Tags: c#, multithreading

So I don't have a lot of in-depth knowledge about threads. I know basic things like starting a timer on a thread or invoking a text box when you need to use it in a different thread. I used threads in this current application so that the process I was doing ran in the background and it worked perfectly.

To get to the problem

I have disabled my form borders and for those of you who have does this knows that there is no form draggability anymore (I did this for aesthetics). It's not an issue I coded the method in order for me to get it moveable again. This is how it looks:

```
 public static class UserMouseEvents
    {
        //is the mouse being pressed
        private static bool mouseDown;

        //where was the pointer last
        private static Point lastLocation;

        //on which form is it coming from
        private static Form originForm;

        public static Form OriginForm { get => originForm; set => originForm = value; }

        public static void UserMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseDown = true;
            lastLocation = e.Location;
        }
        public static void UserMouseUp()
        {
            mouseDown = false;
        }
        public static void UserMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mouseDown)
            {
                OriginForm.Location = new Point(
                (OriginForm.Location.X - lastLocation.X) + e.X, (OriginForm.Location.Y - lastLocation.Y) + e.Y);

                OriginForm.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

It works like a charm. I made it a static method for easy access throughout all my forms. Now I got a problem where a needed two forms to be open at the same time.

It is supposed to simulate a call. So on the one form, I have a user interface similar to a cellphone and it's running a timer (just using the timer class, nothing too fancy). On the other form, I can log notes for the call, maybe view details about who is calling. So for this using just ShowDialog() did not work I had to create a new thread where the cellphone form runs on. This ensured that I can switch between the forms without trouble.

I have to call the UserMouseMethods in the second thread. Just for a little further explanation on each element, I want the draggability to work for I need to call the UserMouseDown, UserMouseMove and UserMouseUp on that elements events. For example pnlHeading_MouseDown, pnlHeading_MouseMove, pnlHeading_MouseUp

Now I do it exactly the way I use to do it for all the other forms and I get this error

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'CallForm' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

CallForm is the cellphone form

I have been sitting on the internet trying to figure out how to make the class accessible at the same time to both the threads and I have officially run into a brick wall.

Can anybody help?

**NOTE**: I have tried methodInvoker, I am unsure if I did it correctly. This was the latest thing in my series of attemps to fix the problem...

**EDIT**: I think I figured out why exactly I am getting the error. So in order for the method to know which form it is supposed to be doing the draggability on, I need to parse the OriginForm to it. So what I do on both forms OnLoad Events, I say

```
UserMouseEvents.OrginForm = this;
```

So then what I assume happens is that the CallForm puts that resource into a lock. So when I try to access it again on the main form. It tells me that I am trying to access CallForm on another thread that it was not created on.

This might provide some insight.

Comment: The MethodIvoker/Dispatcher is the way to go. The UI will always be bound to a single thread.

Comment: Would you provide a little more detail as to how to use it in this specific scenario? I have tried this earlier today and could not seem to get it to work. I tried to put the UserMouseEvents.OriginForm = this; in the method invoker should this be done everywhere that I call the classes' methods. And should this be done in the main form as well.

Comment: Why do you make that static? Just add an instance to any Form where you need the behavior.

Comment: "I made it a static method for easy access throughout all my forms." Using static state that is accessed by many threads won't fly. Using `static` as an alternative to `global` is at the heart of your problem.

Comment: "So for this using just ShowDialog() did not work I had to create a new thread where the cellphone form runs on. This ensured that I can switch between the forms without trouble."  Use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()` if you want to be able to switch between those forms...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the solution to the problem was much simpler than I anticipated. If you look at my edit what I said there is where the issue is. Basically what happened is that I set the

```
UserMouseEvents.OriginForm = this;
```

On the form load of both forms, doing this means that it only runs that line once. So then when I try to move on the call form it overrides the OriginForm and then when I want to move again on the main form it's trying to move the CallForm, but its on a different thread.

Simple solution: 
Move this:

```
UserMouseEvents.OriginForm = this;
```

To the Activate event on the form.

A lot of you said that my method shouldn't be static. I, however, will leave it as static now. I don't have a lot of time to fix that. Also, I would appreciate if you could comment on this answer as to why it shouldn't be static. This was never I rule I was taught in class, or something I learnt while doing courses, watching videos etc.